# twitter typeahead.js Не отображает все результаты

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Проблема в том что если попадаются в результате одинаковые поля, оно почему то показывает только 2.

[image: Отображает только 2 результата из 3х]

```
var dataShipImportConsigne = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url: '/shipment/shipment-importer-consignee-json',
        prepare: function (query, settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            //settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            settings.data = {search: query};

            return settings;
        }
    }
});

typeahead_ship.typeahead(null, {
    name: 'search',
    displayKey: 'full_name',
    source: dataShipImportConsigne,
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'Nothing found <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addShipImpCons" href="#">Add new</a>',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div>{{full_name}} ({{address_1}}, {{address_2}}, {{city}}, {{zip_code}})</div>')
    }
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, data) {

}).on('typeahead:open', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся сегодня.

Ошибка в плагине.

### 1й способ. Исправление кода вручную:

В файле typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js
Строки 1723 и 1724 поменять местами

```
rendered += suggestions.length;
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
```

Должно стать

```
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
rendered += suggestions.length;
```

Если файлы bloodhound.js и typeahead.jquery.js подключаете по-отдельности - найти это место и исправить аналогично

### 2й способ. Установка пропатченного варианта

К сожалению, исправления в "официальный" форк не выходят 2 года.

Можно поставить неофициальный https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/tree/v0.11.1

Но! В релизе ошибка и там не исправлена. Можно поставить master-версию.

Установка bower-ом.

```
bower install --save corejs-typeahead#master
```